# Shall I always stick to the same move if it works?

Tags: basketball, tactics, sports-psychology

I play basketball and my strongest move is right hand hook shot. I comfortably shoot over 50%. I hit even better if I shoot from left using the board. I can finish a post move this way, but also do a running hook shot.

For some reason though, I can never force myself to do it again and again. Even after 3 successful shots in a row, I try to change my next offensive move. I interrupt the hook shot with a fake (defender does not go for it) and try to go under anyway. Or I turn into the hook shot but immediately turn the other way and try a fade-away shot. Or just shoot from the line. All these other moves give me worse shooting percentage.

I think, that I worry too much, that the game will become boring for the others. Is it a valid concern? Or shall I just "play to win"?
Regarding tactics and development, is there any reason to abandon a move that works and force myself to try different moves?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you playing in a league where the goal is to win every game or pick-up games where you play for fun?

In a league, if you have a shot that has 100% accuracy and your opponent has no way to prevent you from shooting, then you owe it to your team to abuse the setup. There's 4 things that can happen. Your opponents complain, the league bans the setup/shot, your opponents improve defensively or they mimic the setup.

In a pick-up game is where this may be opinion based. Is it a serious turf war scenario? Abuse it. Is it for fun? Why not practice other shots and try stupid shots in order to improve your other skill sets. If they stop playing with you, pick-up on the clue and change it up.

This may be opinion based, but unless it's a play-to-win scenario, try to make it fun for everyone. If you play for fun and have nothing to lose, try to do "fun stuff".

Comment: Thank you for your opinions. I used to play in school league many years ago and I would in fact go for the same move as much as possible, because opponents at school level could never really block or stop a hook shot. Never thought about it for a second - I played to win. These days, I only play for fun with various mixed groups. I often play with guys, who would shoot 3pointers every time by themselves. We win, but I hate that game. I guess, that I don't want to be that guy. You are right - it has to be fun for everyone.

Comment: So I will treat my concerns as valid. Even if I could score in next possession easily, I will rather think, whether I could involve others somehow too. Afterall, I can always take over a close game in final minutes.

Comment: @ygor You made a decision to play for fun, good for you. While I am a competitive guy in nature, I am not one to play to win. I play to improve. When the time comes to show I am better, I will play to win. Otherwise I will try stuff I would never try in a competitive situation.

Answer (score 6):

If

1. Something works
2. You're playing to win (see akadian's answer for the issues here), and
3. You're not interested in moving up to a higher standard of play

then by all means keep doing it.

However, if you *are* interested in moving up to a higher standard of play, you'll probably find players and/or teams who are adept at shutting down a one-dimensional player, either by putting a "shut down" defender on you, or by adjusting their team defense so that you're denied the ball in the first place. At that point, if you've got nothing else to fall back on then you're going to struggle.